# How can I use the universal robot package with gazebo?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ur10, universal-robots

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the universal_robots_ros_driver ( https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver)
package with a ur manipulator. However, I can't find any documentation regarding how to do this. All of their documentation, states how to setup ROS using real hardware. I just want to play around sending commands to a simulation. Could you please provide an examle (i.e. roslaunch ur_gazebo ur5.launch and launch the ur_control)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360660/how-can-i-use-the-universal-robot-package-with-gazebo?/) by [StewartHemm74](https://answers.ros.org/users/39655/stewarthemm74/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2020-08-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-01**:
Please do not delete questions with answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> All of their documentation, states how to setup ROS using real hardware. I just want to play around sending commands to a simulation.

Then it makes sense you can't find anything, as the driver is not used with Gazebo.

Only with real robots, or with ursim.

> Could you please provide an examle (i.e. roslaunch ur_gazebo ur5.launch and launch the ur_control)?

No, because as stated earlier, `ur_robot_driver` is not used with Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StewartHemm74](https://answers.ros.org/users/39655/stewarthemm74/) on 2020-08-31**:
So then there is no way to remap topic names or provide a ip_address of the robot in gazebo?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-31**:
I don't understand your question.

Remapping topics is not something which only "works" when using the driver.

And only the driver uses IP addressing information, as it has to communicate with a UR controller. In the context of Gazebo, the IP address "of the robot" is not something which makes sense, as ROS topics / services / actions are used to communicate with the `ros_control` controllers running there.

Perhaps if you can provide some description of what it is you *actually* want to do, we can provide a better answer.

**Comment by [nullspace](https://answers.ros.org/users/57539/nullspace/) on 2020-11-01**:
or atleast anyone say how to simulate it in gazebo by sending joint state coordinates

**Comment by [nullspace](https://answers.ros.org/users/57539/nullspace/) on 2020-11-01**:
i want to control robot joints coordinate by publishing but i dont know how to do it please any one suggest any tutorial(other than construct-youtube videos) or any book